# Branch Micro Optimisation

Tags: optimization

```
            if (m_size == m_capacity - 1)
                resize(m_capacity * 1.2);
```

My question really came about when thinking about the deep CPU pipelines and a small snippet of code. To my understanding what would be done here is two instructions which are dependent on each others result so we'd have, assuming a worse case.

(m_capacity - 1) --- Wait --- (Result == m_size) --- Wait --- Branch Miss

unless we stored m_capacity with the modification pre computed.

(m_capacity == m_size) --- wait --- Branch Miss

I'm not sure how long those waits would be and I'm sure they'd be CPU specific, but would it be worth performing such optimisation or does the CPU have a workaround for this?

Even though it probably wouldn't be recommended to optimise on a micro scale, it's still nice to know what would happen.

Comment: But surely the "do the resize" case is rare and slow? And you want to reduce it by 1 cycle?

Comment: It was really an example, I was wondering if that minus really was one cycle.

Comment: It depends of course, but usually integer subtraction would be 1 cycle, certainly significantly less than a branch missprediction (otherwise there's really no point in doing branch prediction in the first place)

Comment: But the next instruction would depend on the answer of the instruction in front if you it. It might use one cycle, but how long would it take to go through the pipeline and its result be ready for the next instruction to use.

Comment: One cycle. It will be fetched, decoded and dispatched, and *then* it will wait, right before the execution stage, until its operands are ready. When the operands are ready (which they are immediately after execution of the instruction that produced it, not after retirement), it will immediately execute. So the waiting time between two dependent instructions is just the execution time of the first instruction.

Comment: Not sure why this got a -1 it was a good question on instructions which depend on the previous result.

Comment: @harold If you post that comment as the answer, I'll accept it.